# How to define a button with selenium without executing "find_element"? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I really like to pre-define locators and assign them to variables in my test automation project so I could just refer to the variable name later on like this:

```
login_button = <browser>.find_element_by_id("login")
login_button.click()
```

The problem is that if these locators are saved in 'File A' and I import this file into 'File B' (at the very beginning of the program) than those "find_element" methods are executed during the import process while the pages that contain those buttons are not loaded yet which of course leaves me with an exception.

How can I save buttons into variables and import the containing file in the very beginning?

Comment: save _...(which)..._ buttons into variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can store such variables as strings, eg:

```
login_button_click = "driver.find_element_by_id('login').click()"
```

And then when required use:

```
exec(login_button_click)
```

Comment: I am a beginner so I have to ask:
Is this safe?
Is this considered as good practice?

Comment: Some people say the safest way is not to use exec, or eval. Imagine someone can corrupt your files where you store your variables and insert some dodgy code without you noticing. It does work, though.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should divide your files like this:

***file_a:***

```
def click_login(driver):
    login_elem = driver.find_element_by_id('login')
    login_elem.click()


def send_username(driver, username: str):
    login_elem = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
    login_elem.send_keys(username)


def send_password(driver, password: str):
    login_elem = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
    login_elem.send_keys(password)
```

***file_b**:*

```
from file_a import *
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
username = "my_username"
password = "my_password"

def preform_login():
    send_username(driver, username)
    send_password(driver, password)
    click_login(driver)
```

For testing, you should use a config file `config.ini` for all your var's.

Again this is just my opinion...

Hope you find this helpful!